# How do I remove air resistance?

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

I have a space simulation, so obviously I don't want gravity or air resistance. Gravity was straight forward to turn off, but I can't find the equivalent for air resistance. I presume it's going to be on a body-by-body basis rather than a world wide setting like gravity.

Indeed I see on `btSoftBody` that there are values for medium density like `air_density` but I am using `btRigidBody`.

Comment: What are you speaking about ? What software are you using ?

Comment: @Offirmo Bullet physics library, see tag

Comment: Does Bullet even model air resistance for rigid bodies? I don't think it does, though I might be wrong.

Comment: @Bart Oh, well somehow my objects in space appear to slow down and stop, rather than carry on at the same speed unimpeeded. But maybe that's an illusion, I will check the velocities.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no air resistance in bullet physics but there is damping

For every body you create you should set damping calling

```
body->setDamping(linear, angular);
```

set `linear` to be 0

Comment: Not tried it yet, but checks out in the documentation, thanks!

Comment: What are the effect of changing default values of `m_linearSleepingThreshold` and `m_angularSleepingThreshold`?

Comment: To stop the sleeping effect, I had to additionally add the following:

`body->setSleepingThresholds(btScalar(0), btScalar(0));`